# Error during sysprep

Tags: windows, sysprep

I have a recurring problem using sysprep on our Windows 10 machines. I use sysprep with an answer file. When I send our windows image on machines with almost the same hardware, everything works perfectly.

However, lets say my source machine is a ASUS and I decide to sysprep my Windows 10 installation and send it to a HP machine, I get this message:

+++
Error message "The Computer Restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error" after System Startup
+++

Normally, I can open regedit using Shift+F10 and change the child completion parameter to 3 instead of 1 nd it works but I want to understand and fix this error. I never found any reason why I get this error and how to fix it permanently...

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

To fix this error, delete any settings in the specialize phase of your sysprep answer file (unattend.xml).

Basically, this phase (4 if I remember) should NOT be used anymore. I moved my settings to phase 7 OOBE system and everything works like a charm on any machine.

Hope this helps others!